# Docker Swarm Scheduling Performance with node.id Constraint

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-command

If I created a service with docker swarm specifying e.g. `node.id==node42` as a constraint what would happen from the point of view of the scheduling process? The process would be performed entirely taking into account the constraint or, having specified a constraint that forces the choice to a single node, docker only takes care of verifying if the choice is admissible "skipping" then the whole scheduling process?